# Compare two array and diplay the value 2nd array value which is not present in the 1st array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$data1 -
Array([0] => Array([file_id_fk] => 1)
      [1] => Array([file_id_fk] => 2)
      [2] => Array([file_id_fk] => 5)
      [3] => Array([file_id_fk] => 3) 
      ........ 
      [300]=>Array([file_id_fk] => 3)

$data2 - 
Array([0] => Array
        ([file_id] => 1 
         [file_sender_type] => 1
         [file_sender_id] => 1 
         [file_subject] => test 1)
         ...... 
         [360]=>Array...
```

Here i want to compare `$data1->file_id_fk` with `$data2->file_id` and print the `$data2` values that are not present in `$data1`.

Comment: This is very trivial. Why don't you show us what you've tried already?

Comment: i ll explain the full process if u have any other option please tell me actually this is one sql query qry = query1 NOT IN(query2) this query taks long time to execute so i split both the query and save it in array now i want to check not in condition.

Comment: You really need to put more effort into writing properly and trying to clearly express your needs and requirements. This babbling of yours isn't helping anyone forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got answer friends thank you so much

foreach($data1 as $val)
        {
            $data1[]=$val['file_id_fk'];
        }
        for($i=0 ; $i<=count($data2) ; $i++)
        {
            if(!in_array($data2[$i]['file_id'],$data1))
            {
                $data[] = $data2[$i];
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll want to use `array_diff()`, but being that you want the extra values from `$data2`, you'll want to change the order around:
`array_diff($data2, $data)`.

Read the full documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: Thank You i have tried this but am getting unwanted datas only

Comment: Then you need to clarify your question because `$data1->file_id_fk` and `$data2->file_id` don't exist.

Comment: ya but the values present is file_id and file_id_fk is same i want to compare that and want to retrieve the values that are not present in file_id_fk

Answer (score 0):

Imagine yourself being the PHP Parser. How would you like to see the code you had to parse? I asked myself this question and came up with the following:

```
$valuesThatAreInTheFirstArrayButNotInTheSecond = array_diff($theFirstArray, $theSecondArray);
```

I can't make it much more.

As PHP Parser, I am well documented. There's a website on the so called internet that describes how I do and like to do things. You can find the documentation on how I want to parse `array_diff()` in the PHP.net [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

#### Edit

Because you have an array in an array (inception?), you can use the `current()` function around the array. This will grab the array's current key. As there is only one key in your array, it will always pick that one.

So that will make:

```
$valuesThatAreInTheFirstArrayButNotInTheSecond = array_diff(current($theFirstArray), current($theSecondArray));
```

Showing the difference can be done like this:

```
if (array_key_exists('file_id', $valuesThatAreInTheFirstArrayButNotInTheSecond)) {
    echo $valuesThatAreInTheFirstArrayButNotInTheSecond['file_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work on older PHP versions (I am working with 5.4 currently).

```
$data1ID        = array_column($data1, 'file_id_fk');
$results        = array_filter($data2, function($v) use ($data1ID){
    return !in_array($v['file_id'], $data1ID);
});

print_r($data1);
print_r($data2);
print_r($results);
```

This is my input data and results:

```
/vhost/virtual/sandbox/public/index.php:55
array(5) {
    [0] = array(1) {
        [file_id_fk] = int(1) 1
    }
    [1] = array(1) {
        [file_id_fk] = int(1) 2
    }
    [2] = array(1) {
        [file_id_fk] = int(1) 5
    }
    [3] = array(1) {
        [file_id_fk] = int(1) 3
    }
    [4] = array(1) {
        [file_id_fk] = int(1) 3
    }
}

/vhost/virtual/sandbox/public/index.php:56
array(3) {
    [0] = array(4) {
        [file_id] = int(1) 1
        [file_sender_type] = int(1) 1
        [file_sender_id] = int(1) 1
        [file_subject] = string(6) "test 1"
    }
    [1] = array(4) {
        [file_id] = int(1) 5
        [file_sender_type] = int(1) 5
        [file_sender_id] = int(1) 5
        [file_subject] = string(6) "test 5"
    }
    [2] = array(4) {
        [file_id] = int(1) 7
        [file_sender_type] = int(1) 7
        [file_sender_id] = int(1) 7
        [file_subject] = string(6) "test 7"
    }
}

/vhost/virtual/sandbox/public/index.php:57
array(1) {
    [2] = array(4) {
        [file_id] = int(1) 7
        [file_sender_type] = int(1) 7
        [file_sender_id] = int(1) 7
        [file_subject] = string(6) "test 7"
    }
}
```